# Disable ipv6 autoconfiguration on a specific interface in OSX

Tags: mac-osx, ipv6, mac

Is it possible, either via the command line or C code using the sysctl/fcntl/etc. APIs, to disable IPv6 router solicitations, router advertisement acceptance, etc. on OSX for a specific interface? It seems possible via sysctl from the command line, but only system-wide.

The Linux sysctl equivalent is:

```
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.<ifname>.autoconf=0
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.<ifname>.accept_ra=0
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.<ifname>.accept_redirects=0
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.<ifname>.router_solicitations=0
```

(The last is redundant, probably unnecessary.)

On Linux this does it for one interface, but not all interfaces.

I don't want to disable link-local addressing or prevent a manual configuration using ifconfig, just to get OSX to disable and ignore IPv6 router autoconf stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of interfaces with:

networksetup -listallnetworkservices

And then shut it off on a per interface basis:

networksetup -setv6off "Ethernet 1"